# How can OpenGL transform multiple objects to world space with a single model matrix?

Tags: opengl, matrix, opengl-3, perspectivecamera

A few OpenGL tutorials teach the role of each matrix (model, view and projection matrices). They all agree that the model matrix transforms an object to world space, the view matrix then transforms it to camera space and the projection matrix handles the perspective elements.

What isn't explained is how a single model matrix can transform many objects to different world spaces.

Different objects have different positions in world space and therefore a different modelling transformation must be applied - so how can a single model matrix be used?

Comment: None of them say that it can. They usually change matrices between objects.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas then how can you "fetch" the model view matrix using the library?

Comment: I.e. glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...) etc?

Comment: I believe you are looking for glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix

Comment: If you're using modern, core OpenGL (recommended), there is no need to "fetch" the matrices, because you have complete control over them; you provide your shader program the matrix via uniforms. For compatibility OpenGL, there are many matrix functions such as `glLoadIdentity`, `glPush/PopMatrix`, etc that let you perform operations on them.